# Merge object keys into one key with different name

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript

I have an object like so -

```
{
  MaxQty: 5,
  MinQty: 1,
  Start: 12/05/2021,
  End: 09/06/2021,
  Location: 'Singapore',
  Currency: 'USD',
  Category: 'Other'
}
```

I want to map over this object and display the key value pairs which is fine however for certain values, I want to merge them together under a different key name. This is how I want it rendered -

```
Range: 1 - 5,
Date Range: 12/05/2021 To 09/06/2021,
Location: Singapore,
Currency: USD,
Category: Other
```

Location, Currency and Category do not need to be changed however MaxQty/MinQty and Start/End need to be merged into one key value pair with a different key name.

I tried this -

```
 {Object.entries(left).map(([key, val]) => {
            switch (key) {
              case 'MinQty':
              case 'MaxQty':
                return (
                  <S.ValueContainer key={key}>
                    <Label>Range:</Label>
                    <Text size="small">
                      {`${key === 'Min Qty' && val} - ${key === 'Max Qty' && val}`}
                    </Text>
                  </S.ValueContainer>
                )
              case 'Start':
              case 'End':
                return (
                  <S.ValueContainer key={key}>
                    <Label>Date Range:</Label>
                    <Text size="small">
                      From {val === 'Start Date' && val} To {val === 'End Date' && val}
                    </Text>
                  </S.ValueContainer>
                )
              default:
                return (
                  <S.ValueContainer key={key}>
                    <Label>{key}:</Label>
                    <Text size="small">{val as String}</Text>
                  </S.ValueContainer>
                )
            }
          })}
```

But because I am mapping over every value, it prints out two of 'Date Range' and 'Range'.

I am thinking I need to change the object to what I want it to be before mapping over it but I am unsure as to how to do this the best way.

Comment: u can create new object to what u want before doing mapping ```{Range: `${obj.MinQty} - ${obj.MaxQty}`, 'Date Range': `${obj.Start} To ${obj.End}`,....}```. maybe a function which returns a changed object `Object.entries(objConverter(left)).map...`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can create a new object that contains exactly the key-value pairs you intend to display. Then, there is no need to have special cases when displaying the information.

```js
let o = {
  MaxQty: 5,
  MinQty: 1,
  Start: '12/05/2021',
  End: '09/06/2021',
  Location: 'Singapore',
  Currency: 'USD',
  Category: 'Other'
};
let {MaxQty, MinQty, Start, End, ...res} = o;
res.Range = MinQty + ' - ' + MaxQty;
res['Date Range'] = Start + ' To ' + End;
// map over the entries of the res object instead
console.log(res);
```